# I can't get my data from H2 in Jpa unit test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've managed to get my queries validating in Jpa- meaning they are running, but they're not returning anything and I don't know why.  There seems to be data in my stockdata table, because if I try to insert the same data twice into my table, I get "Unique index or primary key violation", so I seem to be hooking up to a different H2 database.

Here's my code in its entirety, starting with the JUnit test I'm trying to get working.

If you don't see the problem, I'd still love to have any input you may have because I'm learning Spring and Spring boot at the same time and would love any pointers!  Thanks!

```
// the unit test that fails - but should not (the list comes back empty)
package com.myorg.stockService.stockservice;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import com.myorg.stockService.entity.StockData;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {StockServiceConfig.class})
public class StockServiceApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    StockService stockService;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {

        //List<StockData> list = stockService.getAllDailyStockData("TNDM");

        List<StockData> list = stockService.findAll();
        assert(list.size() > 0);
    }

}
```

The Entity class:

```
package com.myorg.stockService.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Index;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "stockdata",
        indexes = {@Index(name="symbol_interval_type_index", columnList="symbol,intervalType", unique=false)}
)
public class StockData extends AuditModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final int DAILY=1;

    private StockKey key;

    @Column
    private float open;

    @Column
    private float high;

    @Column
    private float low;

    @Column
    private float close;

    @Column(columnDefinition="adjusted_close")
    private float adjustedClose;

    @Column
    private int volume;

    @Column(columnDefinition="dividend_amount")
    private float dividendAmount;

    @Column(columnDefinition="split_coefficient")
    private float splitCoefficient;

    public StockData() {}

    public StockData(StockKey key, float open, float high, float low, float close, float adjustedClose, int volume,
            float dividendAmount, float splitCoefficient) {
        super();
        this.key = key;
        this.open = open;
        this.high = high;
        this.low = low;
        this.close = close;
        this.adjustedClose = adjustedClose;
        this.volume = volume;
        this.dividendAmount = dividendAmount;
        this.splitCoefficient = splitCoefficient;
    }

    @Id
    public StockKey getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public void setKey(StockKey key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
    public float getOpen() {
        return open;
    }
    public void setOpen(float open) {
        this.open = open;
    }
    public float getHigh() {
        return high;
    }
    public void setHigh(float high) {
        this.high = high;
    }
    public float getLow() {
        return low;
    }
    public void setLow(float low) {
        this.low = low;
    }
    public float getClose() {
        return close;
    }
    public void setClose(float close) {
        this.close = close;
    }
    public float getAdjustedClose() {
        return adjustedClose;
    }
    public void setAdjustedClose(float adjustedClose) {
        this.adjustedClose = adjustedClose;
    }
    public int getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }
    public void setVolume(int volume) {
        this.volume = volume;
    }
    public float getDividendAmount() {
        return dividendAmount;
    }
    public void setDividendAmount(float dividendAmount) {
        this.dividendAmount = dividendAmount;
    }
    public float getSplitCoefficient() {
        return splitCoefficient;
    }
    public void setSplitCoefficient(float splitCoefficient) {
        this.splitCoefficient = splitCoefficient;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\nStockData [key=" + key + ", open=" + open + ", high=" + high + ", low=" + low + ", close=" + close
                + ", adjustedClose=" + adjustedClose + ", volume=" + volume + ", dividendAmount=" + dividendAmount
                + ", splitCoefficient=" + splitCoefficient + "]";
    }   
}
```

And its composite key:

```
package com.myorg.stockService.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

// This is the composite key class for StockData

@Embeddable
public class StockKey implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String symbol;
    private int intervalType;
    private Timestamp ts;

    public StockKey(String symbol, int intervalType, Timestamp timestamp) {

        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.intervalType = intervalType;
        this.ts= timestamp;
    }

    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }
    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }
    public int getIntervalType() {
        return intervalType;
    }
    public void setIntervalType(int intervalType) {
        this.intervalType = intervalType;
    }
    public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
        return ts;
    }
    public void setTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
        this.ts = timestamp;
    }

}
```

The AuditModel for completeness:

```
package com.myorg.stockService.entity;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(
        value = {"createdAt", "updatedAt"},
        allowGetters = true
)
public abstract class AuditModel implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "updated_at", nullable = false)
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date updatedAt;

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }
}
```

My repo class:

```
package com.myorg.stockService.repository;

import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.myorg.stockService.entity.*;

@Repository
@Transactional
public interface StockRepository extends JpaRepository<StockData, StockKey> {

    //@PersistenceContext
    //EntityManager entityManager;

    @Query("Select s from StockData s where s.key.symbol = ?1 AND s.key.intervalType= ?2")
    public List<StockData> getAllStockData(@Param("symbol") String symbol, @Param("intervalType") int intervalType);

}
```

The stock service class that my JUnit test uses to findAll from:

```
package com.myorg.stockService.stockservice;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.myorg.stockService.entity.StockData;
import com.myorg.stockService.repository.StockRepository;


@Service
public class StockService {

    @Autowired
    private StockRepository stockRepository;

    public List<StockData> getAllDailyStockData(String symbol) {

        return stockRepository.getAllStockData(symbol, 1);
    }

    public List<StockData> findAll() {

        return stockRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

The application class.  Note that the assert also fails in the run method:

```
package com.myorg.stockService.stockservice;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.myorg.stockService"})
public class StockServiceApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StockServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        List<StockData> list = stockService.findAll();
        assert(list.size() > 0);
    }
}
```

The 3 files under my src/main/resources folder:

application.properties:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
logging.level.root=warn
```

data.sql --> Note- I also added this file under src/test/resources, but that didn't help

```
INSERT INTO stockdata(symbol,interval_type,ts,open,high,low,close,adjusted_close,volume,dividend_amount, split_coefficient) VALUES
    ('TNDM', 1, parsedatetime('2018-09-14', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 112.1200, 113.7250, 112.1200, 112.9100, 112.4174, 26055620, 0.0000, 1.0000);
```

schema.sql:

```
// schema.sql:
CREATE TABLE stockdata (

    symbol VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    interval_type INT NOT NULL,
    ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    open DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    high DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    low DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    close DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    adjusted_close DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    volume INT NOT NULL,
    dividend_amount DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    split_coefficient DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(symbol, interval_type, ts)
);
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myorg.stockService</groupId>
    <artifactId>stock-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>stock-service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: You need add to constructor of StockData class, stockKey= new StockKey(...,...., new Date()) ; you need generate a key every time this entity is created.

Comment: Enabling SQL logging would be a good start to finding the issue.

Comment: @Jonathan, there is s constructor with StockKey in the StockData class.

Comment: @Alan, by sell logging, do you mean, "spring.jpa.show-sql=true"?  If yes, that's already in my application.properties.

Comment: @Mike sorry I couldn't explain you well, in the constructor StockData class you need instance stockKey =  new StockKey(); because this key must be generated every time you need to persist it .

Comment: @Jonathan, I only created the default constructor because I had heard that it needed to be present for JPA to work (or something like that).  Is this true?  I'd actually remove the function if it weren't needed as I'd always use the constructor with all the arguments instead (and the key would get created that way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seemed to be a few issues with the posted code when I tried it.

1. I couldn't see the StockServiceConfig.class used for ContextConfiguration in the test class. So I used the StockServiceApplication.class. I also moved this up a level in package structure to get the component scan to find the repository.
2. I don't think the schema.sql is being run. It just lets hibernate do ddl-auto. Set following in application.properties to stop this:

   ```
   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
   ```
3. There's a comment before the CREATE TABLE in schema.sql. Sringboot seemed to concatenate all that together and treated the whole thing as a single comment line. Add a semi-colon after the comment:

   ```
   // schema.sql:;
   CREATE TABLE stockdata (

      symbol VARCHAR NOT NULL,
      ... etc
   ```
4. Your StockKey has getTimestamp and setTimestamp, whereas the field is ts (which matches the schema.sql). Change these to getTs and setTs, or provide suitable annotations for the column name. Also needed a default constructor.
5. StockData extends AuditModel, but your schema.sql doesn't define any of the columns in AuditModel. Either define the columns, or don't extend AuditModel.

Comment: WOW!  You are awesome.  I can't thank you enough!!!  I've learned a lot from your post!  Seriously, I've been at this for days and you come along and solve it all for me- you're the best! :)